# Unable to access joomla site after enabling forcing ssl

Tags: ssl, ftp, joomla

I made a mistake. 
When I logged in joomla site administrator settings and set force SSL on entire site. Only then I realized my mistake. I tried to connect with FTP but either I do not know correct way to do it or it was not enabled in settings.

Is there any way to connect and change settings to restore site?

**Update:** I was able to change force_ssl to 0. But site is still not functional and wants to go to https. Also I'm still unable to access administrator site.

If I recall correctly I also enabled force HTTPS.

How can I change this setting?

Comment: Just discovered: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the host where joomla is installed.

In `configuration.php` file change

```
var $force_ssl = '2';
```

to:

```
var $force_ssl = '0';
```

After that it may be necessary to **empty the browser cache**, otherwise the connection could fail despite the changed settings.

Comment: But I don't have local installation of Joomla.

Comment: Currently trying to connect to server

Comment: I have successfully connected to host server and changed 2 to 0. But site is still unavailable. Is there any option of https I might have changed?

Comment: @TomasGriušys You may need to change the permissions in order to save the file. Are you sure the changing is saved correctly?

Comment: When I save it and open again, it show 0. I see that permissions is 444 on that file

Comment: But if I recall correctly I also set force HTTPS. How could I disable it?

Comment: @TomasGriušys Then I don't know anymore. Try to google for `joomla locked out ssl`. You will find further instructions to solve the problem. Good luck!

Comment: @TomasGriušys When you hopefully fixed it, you may consider to post it here as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Your answer was correct. 
Problem was Chrome cache. Apearently Chrome cached that site is https and no longer allowed to access site with http. Clearing cache solved the issue.